# GraphQL mutation variables

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to do a simple mutation using GraphQL with the GraphiQL interface. My mutation looks like this:

```graphql
mutation M($name: String) {
    addGroup(name:$name) {
        id,
        name
    }
}
```

with variables:

```graphql
{
    "name": "ben"
}
```

But it gives me the error: `Variable $name of type "String" used in position expecting type "String!"`

If I change my mutation to `mutation M($name: String = "default")` it works as expected. This looks like it's related to the type system, but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably defined the input name as a non-null string (something like `type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)` if using js server, or `String!` in plain GraphQL).

So your input in the mutation must match, which means it must also be a non-null string. If you change to the following, it should work:

```
mutation M($name: String!) {
  addGroup(name:$name) {
    id,
    name
  }
}
```

Also if you define a default value as you did, it will be a non-null string.

Finally, you could drop the requirement of being a non-null in the server.

Comment: Incredible the the `!` was the issue... Alas it does make sense!

Answer (score 0):

I think in you `addGroup()` mutation the args for name is of type `String!` that is `new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)` but in your mutation you specify as `String` which conflicts with the type system.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an error like this check your database model, in my case I checked my schema and as mongo pluralizes the words was causing me error but I could fix it, also check the documentation.

```
mutation {
  createProject(
    name:"project two",
    description:"project two"
  ) {
    name
  }
}
```

=> works